# Поймать конец скролла на JQuery

Tags: jquery

Если запустить ниже код, будет видно что производится автоматический скролл в конец объекта. Когда пользователь скроллит вверх до объекта **НАЧАЛО**, как поймать что он достиг начала и выполнить к примеру `alert('Вы достигли начала объекта')`

```js
    function scrollToBottom(el) {
        el.scrollTop = el.scrollHeight;
    }
    scrollToBottom(document.getElementById('result_discussion'));
```

```css
div {
overflow-y:scroll;
height:150px;
}
```

```html
<div id="result_discussion">
<li>НАЧАЛО</li>
<li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li>
<li>КОНЕЦ</li>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот так можно определить, за счет теста пересечения прямоугольников контейнера и элемента

```js
let container = document.getElementById('result_discussion');
let containerRect = container.getBoundingClientRect();
let trackElements = [...document.querySelectorAll('.track')];
let last;
scrollToBottom(container);

container.onscroll = function() {
  trackElements.forEach(el => {
    let r = el.getBoundingClientRect();
    if (intersectRect(r, containerRect) && last !== el) {
      last = el;
      console.log(el.textContent)
    }
  });
}

function scrollToBottom(el) {
    el.scrollTop = el.scrollHeight;
}

function intersectRect(r1, r2) {
  return !(r2.left > r1.right || 
           r2.right < r1.left || 
           r2.top > r1.bottom ||
           r2.bottom < r1.top);
}
```

```html
<div id="result_discussion" style="overflow-y: scroll; height: 150px;">
<li class="track">НАЧАЛО</li>
<li>AAA</li><li>AAA</li><li>AAA</li><li>AAA</li><li>AAA</li><li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li><li>AAA</li><li>AAA</li><li>AAA</li><li>AAA</li><li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li><li>AAA</li><li>AAA</li><li>AAA</li><li>AAA</li><li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li><li>AAA</li><li>AAA</li><li>AAA</li><li>AAA</li><li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li><li>AAA</li><li>AAA</li><li>AAA</li><li>AAA</li><li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li><li>AAA</li><li>AAA</li><li>AAA</li><li>AAA</li><li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li><li>AAA</li><li>AAA</li><li>AAA</li><li>AAA</li><li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li><li>AAA</li><li>AAA</li><li>AAA</li><li>AAA</li><li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li><li>AAA</li><li>AAA</li><li>AAA</li><li>AAA</li><li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li><li>AAA</li><li>AAA</li><li>AAA</li><li>AAA</li><li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li><li>AAA</li><li>AAA</li><li>AAA</li><li>AAA</li><li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li><li>AAA</li><li>AAA</li><li>AAA</li><li>AAA</li><li>AAA</li>
<li class="track">СЕРЕДИНА</li>
<li>AAA</li><li>AAA</li><li>AAA</li><li>AAA</li><li>AAA</li><li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li><li>AAA</li><li>AAA</li><li>AAA</li><li>AAA</li><li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li><li>AAA</li><li>AAA</li><li>AAA</li><li>AAA</li><li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li><li>AAA</li><li>AAA</li><li>AAA</li><li>AAA</li><li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li><li>AAA</li><li>AAA</li><li>AAA</li><li>AAA</li><li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li><li>AAA</li><li>AAA</li><li>AAA</li><li>AAA</li><li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li><li>AAA</li><li>AAA</li><li>AAA</li><li>AAA</li><li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li><li>AAA</li><li>AAA</li><li>AAA</li><li>AAA</li><li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li><li>AAA</li><li>AAA</li><li>AAA</li><li>AAA</li><li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li><li>AAA</li><li>AAA</li><li>AAA</li><li>AAA</li><li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li><li>AAA</li><li>AAA</li><li>AAA</li><li>AAA</li><li>AAA</li>
<li>AAA</li><li>AAA</li><li>AAA</li><li>AAA</li><li>AAA</li><li>AAA</li>
<li class="track">КОНЕЦ</li>
</div>
```

Comment: Сделал по другому. scrollTop() помогло и кода получилось меньше. Добавил результат в ответ

Answer (score 0):

```js
function scrollToBottom(el) {
   el.scrollTop = el.scrollHeight;
}
scrollToBottom(document.getElementById('result_discussion'));
    
    
$('#result_discussion').scroll(function(){
var s = $("#result_discussion").scrollTop();
 if (s == 0) {
 console.log('Вы достигли начала объекта');
 }
});
```

```css
div {
  overflow-y:scroll;
  height:150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result_discussion">
  <li>НАЧАЛО</li>
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>КОНЕЦ</li>
</div>
```